# Fetch data from a json within an external url and getting Content Security Policy Error?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, fetch, content-security-policy

Before reading past this. I am very new to coding. I am especially new to XMLHTTP requests/Fetch.

I am trying to get the data from a JSON file from an external website that is behind a login. Let's say:

https://example.com/booking-api/api/v1/example-availability

I tried to do a simple fetch within the google chrome console:

```
fetch("https://example.com/booking-api/api/v1/example-availability")
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

In return I receive this:

adrum-latest.js:30 Refused to connect to 'https://example.example.net/rest/v1/delivery?client=example&sessionId=e331c348a9994242bd32b18588f0483a&version=2.1.0' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' *.example.com *.example2.com etc.

How can I fetch the json data from this site? Is there a way around the Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'?

My end goal is to grab this information every so often. Let's say twice a day.

Remember, I'm not completely sure what I am doing. I have never really looked into these types of requests. Any help or information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sources `*.example.com *.example2.com` allow subdomains only and do not allow main domains `example.com` and `example2.com`. Use:

```
connect-src 'self' *.example.com *.example2.com example.com example2.com
```